# Indexing POJO in Lucene

Tags: lucene, eclipselink, pojo

Is there a good example out there on how to index POJOs in Lucene - the same thing that JIRA does with Issues?

For example, if you have something like

```
class Book {
  private String author;
  private String title;
}
```

I'd like the text of the author and title fields to be indexed in Lucene so I can search on them.

I know it's possible, but haven't found a good concise example how to do it yet.

I am using EclipseLink, not Hibernate, so Hibernate Search is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

**1) CASE 1:**

If you can expose all the to-be-indexed internal attributes of the POJO via getters.

```
public interface Indexable{}

class Book implements Indexable{}

public interface POJOToLuceneDocumentConverter{    
      Document convert(Indexable obj);    
}

public class BookToLuceneDocumentConverter{
    public Document convert(Indexable obj){
    // build the Lucene document.
 }
}
```

**2) CASE 2:**

If you are restricted not to expose all the to-be-indexed data via getters.

a) Create an Inner class for each POJO you want to index.

b) Have a method in that inner class that reads the attributes from the parent class

c) Build the Lucene document and return the same.

The above methods are naive. If you are looking for something advanced, framework-based, automated, etc, I'm not sure..